# How to group using list index row

Tags: python, pandas

This dataframe :

```
Open_Time_s=['2022-04-30 11:05:00+03:00','2022-04-30 11:10:00+03:00','2022-04-30 12:20:00+03:00','2022-04-30 12:25:00+03:00','2022-04-30 12:30:00+03:00']
    Open_s=[38580.46,   38606.81,   38560.17,   38588.10,   38595.47]
    Close_s=[38606.80,  38600.57,   38588.09,   38595.47,   38584.22]
    CLINE_TYPE_s=['Increase',   'nan',  'Decrease', 'nan',  'nan']
    
df3 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Open Time':Open_Time_s,'Open':Open_s,'Close':Close_s,'CLINE_TYPE':CLINE_TYPE_s},dtype=float,orient='index').transpose()
```

Index list of list df3.index:

```
res=[[0,1],[2,3,4]]
```

Unable to group data with max/min function by 'Open' 'Close' field using  index df3 list of list:

```
result=[]
for i in res:
    result.append([df3.iloc[0,0],
                df3.iloc[0, -3],
                df3.iloc[res[i]].dropna(subset=['CLINE_TYPE']).groupby('CLINE_TYPE').Open.max(),
                df3.iloc[res[i]].dropna(subset=['CLINE_TYPE']).groupby('CLINE_TYPE').Close.min()])
```

expected result:

```
[['2022-04-30 11:05:00+03:00','Increase',38606.81,38600.57],['2022-04-30 12:20:00+03:00','Decrease',38595.47,38584.22]]
```

I want to create df4 from result[] , then connect df3 with df4 according to the condition 'Open time' & 'CLINE_TYPE'

Comment: Are you trying to group by 'CLINE_TYPE' ? 'res' is not a column in your dataframe how can you group by it, although you can use it to select.

Comment: SomeDude, 'res' compiled from indexes df3 by condition, I didn't cite him. 
I want to group list of list index area. 'CLINE_TYPE' as an example, I think this field is not needed for grouping, but needed to get rid of 'Nan'

Comment: SomeDude,
There is an idea to trim the date and hour, this will become a valid field for grouping, given the list of list area index df3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no data in the dataframe to perform grouping to calculate the aggregation function.
Therefore, instead of grouping, areas consisting of indexes res[] are used.
Also, the first value of list is the address of the record of the result of the aggregation function.
If the data allows you to perform a grouping that matches your task condition, then getting the index area is an additional condition.

```
df3[['Open_Min_COR','Open_Max_COR']]=np.nan
    
    for i in res:
        df3.loc[i[0],'Open_Max_COR'] = df3.iloc[i].agg({'Open': 'max'})[0]
        df3.loc[i[0],'Open_Min_COR'] = df3.iloc[i].agg({'Open': 'min'})[0]
```

Comment: Consider adding an explanation of hour your code works to aid future readers